# Sending email using outlook smtp through Node js

Tags: node.js, smtp, office365, nodemailer

I'm trying to send an email using Nodemailer package. I am getting following error may be because of wrong configuration.I have been googled many solutions but unable to resolve it. Thanks.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VdHC.png)

[SMTP Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk3Tv.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can check this make sure to add service option and update nodemailer version ->https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/165

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added service option in configuration , but still getting same error.